# What is an object and how is it different than a variable?

Tags: oop, variables, object

I am a structured programmer and i'm trying to learn OOP by creating an MVC app using Classes.

I still don't understand one thing. What is an object and how is it different than a variable?

Comment: Here we go again pls dont -1. give your reasons. im try to ask question about programming and im here to learn from you guys.

Comment: I didn't -1, but a good start to your research would be the link provided in the answer below, or [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=oop+php). :)

Comment: @josh thanks for that. i was just asking here for the reason that i know many here have good answers about its different and i can get many different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable holds a single piece of data while an object holds many variables and methods that act on those variables.

Since you are a beginner you can go through [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Object-Oriented-PHP-for-Absolute-Beginners/68802)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yikes. This really shouldn't be the accepted answer as it isn't technically accurate.

Comment: @JohnFx there will be a vast description if you will incline towards the answer of this question so i have given the link by which somebody can learn something after posting a single definition.

Comment: The link is fine, that first sentence is what gives me the chills. It reinforces a lot of wrong ideas that beginners have about objects.

Comment: @JohnFx this will be a wrong idea for a beginner initially but not after reading the concept, there are lots of definition regarding the objects but i have provided the most fundamental definition.

Comment: I'm not saying it is incomplete. I am saying it is inaccurate. The distinction between a variable and an object is NOT how many pieces of data it holds. A struct, for example, holds multiple pieces of data and is NOT an object.

Comment: it will be better if you will give an answer to the question.

Comment: No problem. Not trying to be judgmental on your answer, but this concept is SO critical to understanding programming for new programmers, I'd hate to get this person off to a wrong start.

Comment: yes this concept is often very critical to understand without practical application for new programmers

Answer (score 2):

Have you read up on the subject?
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 2):

Best way to learn is to see how others do it, check out the online docs for some popular oop php projects:

- [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/)
- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/)
- [CakePHP](http://api20.cakephp.org/classes)

There are many other examples out there, but these should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: thanks.. What of these 3 is mostly used now??

Comment: That's a good question, would be hard to provide metrics on something like that. Personally I use all 3, but mostly Symfony. They went through a heavy re-write from v1 to v2, but either version demonstrates excellent oop usage examples.

Comment: oh.. great ill try symfony as a start. Thanks so much

Comment: I'd like to mention CodeIgniter as well. its easy to pick up since they have very extensive documentation

Answer (score 1):

Some basic concepts you need to understand:

A **variable** is a symbolic reference to data stored in memory. In the simplest case it holds a scalar value (a simple value like "12"), but can also an address to an object (see below).

An **Object** is the actual data stored in memory, but unlike a simple variable it can represent both data and functionality (methods) that acts on that data.

A **Class** is a template for an object. It contains a definition for the types of data that will be stored and the code for the methods. Think of it like a recipe for an object, but it is not itself an object.

Don't get confused by the other (Accepted) answer, by the distinction of having multiple values. That really isn't the distinction between a class and object. Structured data types (structs), for example, can also hold multiple values, but are not objects by the strictest definition.